# Threads or Background Process Cake php

Tags: cakephp-2.3

How do i manage to send automated mails using threads or some background process a month later from now in cakephp. Can anyone please help me. Thanks in advance

Am new to cakephp and need to know how to use backprocess. So please help me in this.

Comment: It's good to know you found the right site to post this question, but you still have to improve it a lot before it can be answered. Please post the code you tried, and explain the problems you're encountering with it.

Comment: Sorry Hamidi i don't have any idea about this.. I need to somehow start so decided to ask help from you guys.

Comment: Then I'm afraid Stack Overflow is not the right resource for this (*maybe* the chat rooms, and I'm really not sure). We aim to solve concrete problems, and cannot help you design and implement your project from scratch.

Comment: Thats cool..Then i'll try to start implementing and get back to u in couple of days. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A solution would be to create a cron job that calls a CakePHP url on a daily basis. This action would then access the database, lookup information that is a month old, and process it as needed.

For example, the default format for cron jobs is:

`minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute`

So if you want it to run once a day, say at 6am, and access your site, you would use the following:

`00 06 * * * /usr/bin/wget http://www.example.com/mycontroller/myaction`

Then in your action you would access your data as you would normally in CakePHP. For example:

```
public function myaction()
{
    $searchDate = $fromDate = date('YY-m-d', strtotime("-1 months"));
    $myData = $this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('created' => $searchDate)));
    foreach($myData as $thisData)
    {
        //Process as needed here
    }
}
```